# Problem on computing the Fourier transform of the Gaussian

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, gaussian-integral

The problem sounds like this.

> Show that $s\to\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-(x+is)^2}dx$ is constant wrt
>   $s\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then use this fact to shot that
>   $\mathcal{F}(e^{-a|x|^2})=e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{a}}$ for $a>0,$ where
>   $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$

I know the traditional ODE way to show this fact about the Gaussian bell but this proof got me interested and I don't have any clue on solving this. I've tried to differentiate wrt $s$ but no luck.

Comment: Yes the claim is more than sloppy. For $s \in i\mathbb{R}$ the constantness is obvious from a change of variable. But the function is analytic in $s \in \mathbb{C}$, thus being constant on some interval implies constant everywhere, in particular constant in $s \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ok thanks, now the part about that constant function is clear. I still don't know how to show the last part of the problem.

Comment: Expand $(x+is)^2$ you'll see the Fourier transform of $e^{-x^2}$ and with a change of variable the FT of $e^{-a x^2}$

Comment: I still don't get it..